# How to arrange two divs with different ids in the same line?

Tags: html, css

The current code is as follows:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px transparent;
}

div#myDiv1 {
  -webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

div#myDiv2 {
  -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv1">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">a</p>
</div>
<div id="myDiv2" class="right">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">b</p>
</div>
<div id="myDiv1">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">c</p>
</div>
```

[image]

This is how I want to arrange it. The skew in the same row should be opposed to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is you want, but I just did it the same as the image. I added a `wrapper` for each row, and some css to make the `divs` inline

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline;
}

div#myDiv1 {
  -webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
}

div#myDiv2 {
  -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
}

div#myDiv3 {
  -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="myDiv1">
    <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">a</p>
  </div>
  <div id="myDiv2" class="right">
    <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">b</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="myDiv3">
    <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">c</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: however，how do you arrange the code if you want to print "abcdef" in the same order?

Comment: the same as how I did the `ab` part, change it to `cd`, `ef`, etc. adjust the css as necessary

Comment: the problem i'm facing now is by doing this:

Comment: <div class="wrapper">
 <div id="myDiv1">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">a</p>
 </div>
 <div id="myDiv2" class="right">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">d</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="myDiv1">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">b</p>
 </div>
 <div id="myDiv2" class="right">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">e</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="myDiv1">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">c</p>
 </div>
 <div id="myDiv2" class="right">
  <p class="mt15 colorc1 center font16">f</p>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: it will display in a same line, but i wanted to display it in to coloms